# Back Button On Fragment ActionBar Search

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, back-stack, android-searchmanager

I have an android search in action bar (just standard one). The way I made it working is, I created `SearchQueryRouter` Activity, which receives search query and starts the `MainActivity` - where all my `Fragments` reside replacing each other. Everything works perfect so far. BUT once I hit android **back button** it redirects "back" (sarcasm) to blank activity or fragment or whatever so that Nothing is Logged (I log messages once `onCreate` executes).

Any idea on how to support back button functionality properly? - I expect back button to push me either to previous search or to the default results on the Fragment.

This is my `MainActivity` (Mother of Fragments)

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    MyFragment newFrag = new MyFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("searchQuery", bundle.getString("searchQuery"));
    newFrag.setArguments(args);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFrag);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Here is `SearchQueryRouter`

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
    Intent newIntent = new Intent();
    newIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    newIntent.putExtra("searchQuery", query);
    finish();
}
```